# Android webview not accept .co or .org extensions

Tags: android, webview

i am using android webview

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.mywebsite.co/");
```

but i could not load .co and .org extensions

Comment: Please make sure you have internet permission and the url you are trying to load is proper.Check it by opening it in browser because i was able to load https://www.wikipedia.org/ this url.

Comment: If it was internet permission problem then even .com website should not load , Please add your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added the internet permission in your manifest file ? if not add the following line.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

or maybe SSL problem

Comment: i already given these permissions but it will successfully load url with .com extension

Comment: maybe you have problem with ssl

Comment: try setting javascriptenabled(true) to your webview